# Profile command issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a simple profile command. When there is no mention bot shows your profile, when there is mention, bot shows profile of mentioned user.

```
#!профиль - профиль
@client.command(passContent=True, aliases=['profile'])
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def профиль(ctx, member):
    colour=member.colour
    if member==None:
        профиль_сообщение=discord.Embed(
            title=f'Профиль {member.name}',
            colour=colour
            )
        await ctx.send(embed=профиль_сообщение)
    else:
        return
```

When I am using command WITHOUT mention I get this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show your profile when the `member` parameter's empty, you can give a value to it. For example you can do `async def профиль(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):`. That means, if user doesn't fill the `member` parameter, it'll be `None`. Then in the code, you can add:

```py
@client.command(passContent=True, aliases=['profile'])
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def профиль(ctx, member):
    colour=member.colour
    if member==None:
        member = ctx.author
        профиль_сообщение=discord.Embed(
            title=f'Профиль {member.name}',
            colour=colour
            )
        await ctx.send(embed=профиль_сообщение)
```

So if the member is `None`, then it'll be the `ctx.author`.